# Can someone please explain this term/slang “问个P”

Tags: simplified-characters, slang

Is it related to this phrase: 问个屁/問個屁

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's 问个屁. P -> 屁.

问个屁 means *Don't ask!*. It indicates that you are annoyed by the questioner. It's a way to block their questions to annoy you any further.

It's a ruder way to say 别问了！

Answer (score 2):

Politely, roughly 'nonsense'. Various less polite Anglo-Saxon expletives may be substituted.

问个屁 Ask/Talk nonsense.

你错了
You are wrong.
错个屁!
Wrong my foot!

Comment: Usually when someone say something like this, s/he generally means "mind your own business" or "back off" after being asked about something upset.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but for 'mind your own business', wouldn't you prefer: "你问什么问，管好你自己吧！“ 或者 ‘有什么好问的， 管好你自己吧！” Dan is of course right, 问个屁 really tells the person to stop, don't ask, because the question is stupid or annoying or nonsensical.

Comment: Yeah, but this is a quick way to stop the question. Such meaning is also implied. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the pronunciation of 屁 is pi (4th tone). Very close to the English letter P.

Answer (score 1):

It means:

What are you asking for? This is nonsense.